# Flux.interval does not emits the values for new events/ object created

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

`Once the new Object is been added in a pipeline i can see the value(obj.url) of the new Object being printed without getting executing the Flux part.`

- Note: If i restart my application, it able to read all the objects and executes completely.
- Issue: Seems like flux.interval is not getting subscribed for the
  new events.

The new real time value will be added into a Map<String, BaseSubscriber>
Once added it will invoke startPipeline() method where it get printed with a new value but it wont execute after that . So here the real time added objects wont be executed with `getMessages()` and `doSomeTask()` method.

```
class pipelineProcess extends BaseSubscriber<Data>{

 private final XYZ obj;

 @PostConstruct
 public void startPipeline() {

 log.info("New Objected read {} ",obj.getUrl())

 Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(500))

                .flatMapIterable(aLong -> getMessages())

                .flatMap(message -> doSomeTask(message))

                .subscribe(this);

    }
}
 @Override
    protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        log.info("Hook on Subscribe called for {} : ",obj.getUrl());
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnNext(ScanRequestData next) {
        log.info("Hook on Next called for {}: ", obj.getUrl());
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnError(Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("hookOnError exception", throwable);
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnComplete() {
        log.warn("The reactor pipeline of {} has been completed.", obj.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnCancel() {
        log.warn("The reactor pipeline of {} has been cancelled.", obj.getUrl());
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here - could you elaborate? What are you trying to read from? If you can post a [mcve] that would help.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I have a stream pipeline where we add SQS url and pipelineProcessObject in the Map. `Map<String, BaseSubscriber>` Once the new value been added into the map. `@PostConstruct startPipeline()` method will be invoked as shown in the above code snippet. but surprisingly able log the new values `log.info("New SQS url is {} ",obj.getUrl())`, but the new event is not being subscribed for the Flux.interval by which we not able to process the new events we are able to process the old events only.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the flux there inherently - have you tried putting `log()` statements in the reactive chain to check where it's going wrong?

Comment: Yes i added the log() and checked, but the new events wont be included in the reactive chain i see the old list which gets processed. But if i restart the applications it starts including new events in the reactive chain.

Comment: If that's the case (it keeps processing the old events) then that implies `getMessages()` has an issue where it's returning the old, not the new messages - I'd search there for your issue.

Comment: No thats not the issue, actually i have added logs even in `getMessage()` i never see the new events coming in getMessage() but Map has the new event in it, still it considers the old Map in emitting the flux. 
But i get the new event processed only when i restart the application.
Thanks for the quick response @MichaelBerry

Comment: No problem, but afraid I'll probably need a self-contained example to suggest anything else - there's not that much else to go on with the code here.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerry found out the issue, As we are processing a huge load in less interval of time where data is getting overlapped due to thisFlux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(500)) .
I tried increasing Durations.OfSeconds(30) and as it is overriding `hookOnSubscribe` where request(1), i changed it to request(Long.MAX_VALUE)